# How to open a modal in javascript instead of manual click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have a modal which is open when i click on a button. Now i want to open the modal in a javascript function. 
Here is the working modal :

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" id="sentMessage" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#largeModal">Click to open Modal</a>
    <div class="modal fade" id="largeModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="largeModal" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Large Modal</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <h3>Modal Body</h3>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

I want to open the same modal in a javascript function. So to simulate this function, i create another button which trigger a function :

```
<a href="#" ng-click="openModal();" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary">Click to execute js</a>
```

Here is my openModal function :

```
$scope.openModal = function(){
    $("#sentMessage").click();

};
```

When i click on the button "Click to execute js", the modal does not open. 
Here is the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/JM9UALvZMx6FGzUqvrEB?p=preview)

Answer (score 46, accepted):

you can use the modal function:

```
$('#largeModal').modal('show');
```

Comment: This uses jQuery, but the question asked for javascript.  They are not the same thing.

Comment: @j_allen_morris If you look in the OP his question you can see he uses jQuery.

Comment: You're right. I hate that people use it synonymously.  Maybe it doesn't happen as much as it did 5 or more years ago.